# How to display proper value of a member of parent class in child class method

Tags: c#

How can I get the child class method showvalue() to display a proper value that i input from the parent class member getvalue(), it only displays zero

```
class parent
{
    public int value;
    public void getval()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter value: ");
        value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
class child:parent
{
    public void showvalue()
    {
        Console.Write("Child: "+value);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        parent obj1 = new parent();
        child obj = new child();
        obj1.getval();
        obj.showvalue();
        Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are confused about some things here. You are using inheritance. You don't need the `obj1` declaration, and the `getval` should be on `obj`. Both `obj1` and `obj` are completely independent from eachother, you just created 2 classes, for which `obj` shares only the method from the parent, but the fields are owned by the class itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj1` and `obj` are different instances which do not share instance fields between each other. Assume you have entered `5` for parent object:

[image]

You should create single instance of `child` type:

```
    parent obj = new child();
    obj.getval();
    obj.showvalue();
```

Thus child inherits `value` field from parent, you will have an access to that field and value which you store there.

Note: use *PascalCase* names for method and class names.

Further reading: [C# - Inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm)

Comment: Thank man it works and sure I will further read on C# inheritance its different then the C++

Comment: @DarvinTheory I have added you rough image which explains that you have two objects with different type and each with its own copy of fields

Comment: great man, can i ask one question from you related to this program ??

Comment: @DarvinTheory it depends. What is the question?

Comment: if this hierarchical class inherit two child classes one child-class +1 the value from a method in it another -2 the value from a method in it and the display will be resultant from the action that those child classes perform on it

Comment: @DarvinTheory you cannot inherit two classes in c#

Comment: @DarvinTheory sorry, I don't get your question here

Comment: like
A{value=5;}
B:A{value+1;}
C:A{
value-2;
displays value that is added and subtracted;
}

Comment: @DarvinTheory class `C` is not related to class `B`. Why something should be added in your pseudocode from class `C`? Please read more about inheritance in c#

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
obj.getval()
```

Instead of

```
obj1.getval()
```

Otherwise your objects don't have any connection. Always use the child object for stuff like that.